# how do I set a debug mode in c++

Tags: c++

I would like to set a debug mode so that it prints the log statements only if the debug mode is on. For example if I have code like this

```
printf("something \n");
.
.
.
perror("something \n");
```

It only works if the debug flag is on.. I don't want to use "if" statements.
I think there is a clever way to do this using #define or something..

Thank is advance..

Comment: You need a logging framework with error-levels!

Comment: Any particular compiler / platform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without going in to specific libraries or solutions, generally people make a logger class or function, and a single debug flag. The debug function checks this flag before calling printf or cout. Then in the rest of your code you simply call your debug function / method.

Here's an example:

```
class MyDebugger
{
    private:
        bool m_debug;

    public:
        MyDebugger();
        void setDebug(bool debug);
        void debug(const char* message);
};

MyDebugger::MyDebugger()
{
    m_debug = false;
}

void MyDebugger::setDebug(bool debug)
{
    m_debug = debug;
}

void MyDebugger::debug(const char* message)
{
    if(m_debug)
    {
        cout << message << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyDebugger debugger;
    debugger.debug("This won't be shown");
    debugger.setDebug(true);
    debugger.debug("But this will");

    return 0;
}
```

of course this is an incredibly naive implementation. In real logger classes there are many levels for finer-grained control of how much detail gets printed (levels like error, warning, info, and debug to differentiate the importance of the message). They might also let you log to files as well as stdout. Still this should give you a general idea.

Comment: Incurs unnecessary runtime penalty.

Comment: @Ajay: you seem to be assuming that the program knows a priori what the debug level will be, which isn't always the case. Also, it's a logger -- if you're calling it millions of times per second, you're clearly not doing it right. Performance isn't all that important.

Comment: @Ajay: You don't know that. To be a computational burden the logger would have to be called many, many (hundreds of thousands of times) times per second. A performance monitor typically won't see a logging function as a blip on the radar when logging is disabled. There is a penalty to logging, but it is a human penalty, not a runtime one. You do not want to wade through a log file with thousands of lines generated per second. Log files are for low frequency events. As Chris said, performance isn't all that important.

Answer (score 10):

```
#ifdef _DEBUG // or #ifndef NDEBUG
#define LOG_MSG(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__) // Or simply LOG_MSG(msg) printf(msg)
#else
#define LOG_MSG(...)                     // Or LOG_MSG(msg)
#endif
```

On non-Debug built `LOG_MSG` would yeild to nothing. Instead of defining it with raw printf, you can have your custom logging-function, or class-method to be called.

Comment: _DEBUG should be a boolean type variable?

Comment: On VC++ _DEBUG is defined when you are building the Debug build, otherwise undefined. NDEBUG is for GCC/NetBeans. These macros are either #defined or NOT #defined (generally with 1). These are macros, and not variables.

Answer (score 2):

In GCC, something like

```
#define debugprint(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple C-style macro definition (especially if you compiler is modern enough to do variable arguments macros, i.e. gcc or VS2005+) doing printf with a check of the debug level which can be a static global variable.
If you go with C++-style class similar to what @Chris suggests, I would make the logging function inline to ensure that when logging is disabled you are not wasting time on calling functions.

Comment: Re "I would make the logging function inline to ensure that when logging is disabled you are not wasting time on calling functions." Why? That is a case of premature optimization. The cost of a function call that quickly returns is negligible given the modern approach of attacking problems via an amalgamation of compiled code and scripting languages.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that if something is written in C++ (as opposed to C#/Java/Python/Ruby) at this point, performance is crucial.  Of course depends on logging.  For instance, if you want to log every packet received, you will most likely benefit from inlining.

Comment: @MKL Suppose you do just that: Log every packet received. Making these functions inlined will have zero benefit. Case 1, logging is enabled. Here the construction and printing of the log file messages will dwarf cost of a function call. Case 2, such logging is disabled. Once again, performance is a non-factor. Packet processing of those packets will dwarf the cost of a call to a do-nothing logging function. In either case you are putting the emphasis on the wrong syllable. Premature optimization is a bad idea (continued).

Comment: (Continuation) The advantages of a logging system as described by Chris are huge. Most importantly, the code does not have to be recompiled to enable logging. A simple change to a configuration file, and voila!, a nice log file is produced. Suppose a customer is having problems with your product. With this feature, you can ask the customer to change some config file, rerun, and email the resulting log file to you. This capability is lost with logging enabled by some compile switch.

Comment: @David well, there is a reason people inline functions, right?  Now to the advantages -- I think you misunderstand me.  Inlining still doesn't require rebuild when changing debug level.  What I do is check the current debug level inline and then if the verbosity of a particular debug line meets current debug setting I invoke the actual debug function.  The penalty of inlining is minimal (no code bloat, just one conditional) and there is no loss in flexibility.